# How I can switch to this popup screen using selenium webdriver java?

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The scenario is ,there is a button when I click on it, this popup is opened as attached image. And I should fill the data in it and click submit button.
I can not switch to this popup using the below code :

```
    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); // get all window handles
    Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()){
        subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler); // switch to popup window
```

Any help will be appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo1oe.png)

Comment: Are you getting the second window Id in the output of handles (set variable)?

Comment: No, I did not get it.

Comment: Did you observe that window opened and still you are not getting the window Id in set variable if this is the case then try to handle those web elements without traversing to the window

Comment: When I did that, the output was that : java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Could you please share the updated code

Comment: @AlaaEldeinAli, Verify whether this popup is modal window, or iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this code after launching the browser :

There is no need to switch as there is no window/alert.

The opened pop up is just a **Div**.

```
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://41.33.122.55:3333/users/login");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("username"))).sendKeys("alaatest");
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("password"))).sendKeys("QWERTY123");  
        WebElement loginButton =   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.btn.btn-white-rounded.login-btn")));  

        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", loginButton);

        WebElement creaetAccount = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[text()='Add new Account']")));
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", creaetAccount);

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("firstName"))).sendKeys("Ali");
```

Answer (score 0):

From my own experince, it takes a few ms to reach the "new" Windowhandle. In Firefox, this works for me:

```
public void goto2 () throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(100);
    ArrayList<String> winHandles = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
    Thread.sleep(100);
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandles.get(1));
}
```

In Chrome you don't even need to switch, the driver do the job itself. At least at new tabs and windows, not sure if on frames too.

If you wanna try Chrome, there is my setup:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\pburgr\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

It includes existing Chrome profile, so you can use extensions, cache, whatever. Just edit path to exe and profile folder.

Comment: This is the output:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Comment: what's the url?

Comment: Scenario is:
1- Login.    2- Click add new account button.  then the popup will be produced.

Answer (score 0):

Complete code for login and reaching firstName field in the modal window. The rest you manage by your own I believe.

```
package navi; // rename this

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class Egypt {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    public WebDriverWait wait1s = new WebDriverWait(driver,1);
    public WebDriverWait wait5s = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
    public WebDriverWait wait10s = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
    public WebDriverWait wait30s = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
    public WebDriverWait wait1m = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
    public WebDriverWait wait2m = new WebDriverWait(driver,120);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();         
        FirefoxProfile selenium_profile = allProfiles.getProfile("selenium_profile");
        options.setProfile(selenium_profile);
        options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", Secrets_and_variables.get_driver_path());
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {}

    @After
    public void tearDown() {}

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {driver.quit();}

    @Test
    public void egypt() throws InterruptedException {

        driver.get("http://41.33.122.55:3333/users/login");
        WebElement fld_username = wait30s.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("username")));
        fld_username.sendKeys("alaatest");
        WebElement fld_pwd = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
        fld_pwd.sendKeys("QWERTY123");
        WebElement btn_login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/div[3]/account-management/login/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[3]/button"));
        btn_login.click();
        wait30s.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/div[3]/request-management/div[2]/accounts-list/div/table/tbody")));
        WebElement btn_add_acc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/app-root/div[3]/request-management/div[1]/div/div[3]/a"));
        btn_add_acc.click();
        WebElement fld_firstName = wait5s.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("firstName")));
        fld_firstName.sendKeys("John");
        Thread.sleep(10000);

    }
}
```